# How to save image files in android mobile gallery in Flex 4.5

Tags: android, directory

I am developing a mobile application in Adobe Flash builder 4.5.

I want to save an image in mobile memory at run time.

Please help me,
 how can i save image in mobile's sdcard or in mobile memory?
and after that i also have to show all images in this directory.

Please help me i dont know how can i access mobile directories or interact  with mobile directories in Flex 4.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

1. Get Image bitmap data through ImageSnapshhot class.
   2.Encode this bitmap data into byte Array using png encoder.
   3.Then use File Class to save this byte Array.

here is the code of saving image byte array into sd card

> var fl:File =
>   File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath('savedLogos/'+getNowTimestamp());
>   trace(fl.nativePath)
>
> ```
>           try
>           {
>               var fs:FileStream=new FileStream;
>               fs.open(fl,FileMode.WRITE);
>               fs.writeBytes(bytArray,0,bytArray.length);
>               fs.close();
>           }
> ```

trace command will show this path

/mnt/sdcard/savedLogos/Logo_2011430225732663.png

Image is saved in mobile sdcard and you can see this.

Comment: hi, here is something disturbing me. i am using the same "/mnt/sdcard/savedLogos/Logo_2011430225732663.png" path as string in image source to show this image in my application and image is also exist in this path as i am saving it and can see this image in sdcard but it is not loading, don't know why? can anbody tell me about this.